# how to Create an APK that holds a PDF and Displays it on the home page

Tags: android, pdf, apk, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I'm an N0ob so easy to follow instructions please :)
I am trying to build an app to go onto a TOMTOM display, running Andriod 6.0.1.
I have 3 PDF's I want drivers in my fleet to have access to. So the APK (can be 3 separate APK's) needs to have the PDF file embedded so it loads as part of the image file... I can't go around and load the PDF's onto each device. and the APK needs to create a Home screen shortcut to each PDF.
 Any ideas?? Does anyone want to make the APK for fun? :P

Comment: `Does anyone want to make the APK for fun?` nope, this isn't a coding service, you are welcome to code something yourself and ask for help here when trying to achieve what you want

Comment: thanks, it was meant as a cheeky request/joke

Answer (score 0):

You can view the pdf by two ways i.e by opening by in-built browser or through the webview which is embedded in your app.

Open in webview,

```
Webview webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("You google drive link.pdf");
```

Open in in-built browser,

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("You google drive link.pdf")
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: thanks for this, is there a way of embedding the pdf files into the APK?